# print string by using Scanner class

Tags: java, string, printing

I am giving this input "Welcome to HackerRank's Java tutorials!" into  but

printing only "Welcome" string through scanner class.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = scan.nextInt();
        double d = scan.nextDouble();
        String s = scan.nextLine();
        scan.close();

        // Write your code here.

        System.out.println("String: " + s);
        System.out.println("Double: " + d);
        System.out.println("Int: " + i);
    }
}
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: This code in no way can print "Welcome"

Comment: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/java-stdin-stdout/editorial there is answer to your question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please have a better title and more detailed information in the content with your effort to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that your string does not contain the integer and a double value on the input line.

If you provide `12 2.56 Welcome to HackerRank's Java tutorials!`, it will work:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int i = scan.nextInt();
double d = scan.nextDouble();
scan.nextLine();
String s = scan.nextLine();
scan.close();

System.out.println("String: " + s);
System.out.println("Double: " + d);
System.out.println("Int: " + i);
```

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/3cNTzz)

Output:

```
String:  Welcome to HackerRank's Java tutorials!
Double: 2.56
Int: 12
```

If you want to make sure your string gets parsed, check the next token with `hasNext` methods ([`hasNextInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt()) and [`hasNextDouble()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextDouble())):

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int i = 0;
if (scan.hasNextInt())
    i = scan.nextInt();
double d = 0d;
if (scan.hasNextDouble())
    d = scan.nextDouble();
String s = scan.nextLine();
scan.close();
```

See this [demo](http://ideone.com/wG0Te6).

Comment: The above dosen't give a right answer I don't know how it is acceptable

Comment: @Arun It works perfectly well for OP. See [the demo](https://ideone.com/3cNTzz) printing the string, the double and int values. Your requirements just seem different from this OP's. Please post your own question if you still have trouble with your code.

Comment: I hope the  above solution won't work, scan.nextLine(); should be added after scan.nextDouble(); then it got worked.

Comment: @komalakhani  The question is not about how to read multiple lines, but about how to parse a single line (that may or not contain specific data) passed to Scanner. So, it works for the *current scenario in the OP*. At any rate, [this reads all lines](https://ideone.com/V9aYSV).

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("\nEnter The String= ");
        String s = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("\nEnter The int= ");
        int i = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("\nEnter The Double= ");
        double d = scan.nextDouble();   
        scan.close();

        // Write your code here.

        System.out.println("String: " + s);
        System.out.println("Double: " + d);
        System.out.println("Int: " + i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation as to how this solves the problem, or how this differs from the existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/25006327)

Comment: Thanks for Advice @Nick . I will try  my best from next time

Answer (score 1):

**Please write following code..It will work!!**

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int i = scan.nextInt();
double d = scan.nextDouble();
scan.nextLine();
String s = scan.nextLine();
scan.close();

System.out.println("String: " + s);
System.out.println("Double: " + d);
System.out.println("Int: " + i);
```

**NOTE:** If you use the nextLine() method immediately following the nextInt() or nextDouble() [reading tokens of input and reading a full line of input] method, recall that nextInt() or nextDouble() reads integer tokens; because of this, the last newline character for that line of integer or double input is still queued in the input buffer and the next nextLine() will be reading the remainder of the integer or double line.So,you need to make another call to nextLine().

Comment: Your solution [throws `java.util.InputMismatchException`](https://ideone.com/QuiNOu).

Comment: It is Working for me!!

Comment: Great,  I am happy it does for you.

Answer (score 0):

When switching between reading tokens of input and reading a full line of input, you need to make another call to `nextLine()` because the Scanner object will read the rest of the line where its previous read left off.

If there is nothing on the line, it simply consumes the newline and moves to the beginning of the next line.

After double declaration, you have to write: `scan.nextLine();`

Comment: your solution got worked I also given the same comment from yours to other post

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it was successful:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i;
        double d;
        String s;
       
        i = scan.nextInt();
        d = scan.nextDouble();
        scan.nextLine();
        s = scan.nextLine();
        scan.close();
        
        System.out.println("String: " + s);
        System.out.println("Double: " + d);
        System.out.println("Int: " + i);
    }
}
```